# cancel button to close fancybox 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I've created a confirmation windows for a form using fancybox 2.x. Everything with it is working, the form submits and load a fancybox windows with all the proper confirmation information. At the bottom of the confirmation page I have a submit button and a cancel button.

I'm using this code to load the fancybox window when the submit button is clicked.

```
    $("#contact-form").live('submit', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "/form_datas/confirm/",
                data: $("#contact-form").serialize(),
                dataType: 'text',
                success: function(data) {
                    $.fancybox(data, {
                        width:600,
                        closeBtn: false,
                        openEffect: 'none',
                        closeEffect: 'none',
                        onCancel: fancyClose(),
                        onClose: fancyClose(),
                    });
                }
            });

            return false;
    });
```

The buttons on the confirmation window/fancybox modal window:

```
<input class="submit btn button adbtn" id="confirmSubmitBtn" type="submit" value="Confirm">
<button type="button" class="submit btn button adbtn" id="stopBtn">Cancel</button>
```

The below code works with the submit button, but not the cancel button. Any ideas?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#confirmSubmitBtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        parent.$.fancybox.close(true);
        $("#contact-form").submit();
        return false;
    });

    $("#stopBtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        parent.$.fancybox.close(true);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: have you looked at enabling `closeBtn` in the `$.fancybox.defaults`?

Comment: what type of content are you opening: inline, iframe? where the code above is located (parent/iframed page)?

Comment: I'm loading a page via ajax when the submit button is clicked to show a confirmation window. I've updated my first message to include the code I'm using to open the fancybox window. I've disabled the closeBtn as I do not want the site viewers to have the ability to close it by that means.

Comment: I've tried parent.$.fn.fancybox.close(), parent.fancybox.close(), $.fn.fancybox.close(), $.fancybox.close(), I've changed the submit buttons to links and have tried adding these via onclick as well to no avail. It simply does not work and will not close the fancybox window. No errors or warning in chrome or Firefox console windows either. Help?